# What are the best practices for creating linked markup in HTML documents?

Tags: javascript, html, semantics

I have seen a few different ways of creating clickable regions or groups of elements in HTML documents.

One method is to wrap a bunch of elements in an anchor tag and make it display block. Some argue however that this is semantically incorrect. Another way is to use JavaScript, however when not done carefully it can ruin user experience by disabling middle click and right click.

Comment: it's such a rare occasion as it is and if you encounter a situation where you need to wrap several element within a link, i'd say go for it, as you said javascript would just bring a lot of extra and unnecessary work to the table and possible lower the userexperience while wrapping it would in worst case scenario lower your semantics.

Comment: For some clients SEO is a huge deal, if it has an impact I would be cautious. The best I have come up with is adding "nofollow" to random links that wrap elements they semantically shouldn't. How does the nofollow attribute work with nested anchors, are they even valid markup?

Comment: Is this a call for opinions and discussion, or is there a constructive question involved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

W3 say:

(Edit: a link would be nice... [dev.w3.org](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-LC/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element))

> The a element may be wrapped around entire paragraphs, lists, tables, and so forth, even entire sections, so long as there is no interactive content within (e.g. buttons or other links). This example shows how this can be used to make an entire advertising block into a link:

```
<aside class="advertising">
 <h1>Advertising</h1>
 <a href="http://ad.example.com/?adid=1929&amp;pubid=1422">
  <section>
       <h1>Mellblomatic 9000!</h1>
   <p>Turn all your widgets into mellbloms!</p>
   <p>Only $9.99 plus shipping and handling.</p>
  </section>
 </a>
 <a href="http://ad.example.com/?adid=375&amp;pubid=1422">
  <section>
   <h1>The Mellblom Browser</h1>
   <p>Web browsing at the speed of light.</p>
   <p>No other browser goes faster!</p>
  </section>
 </a>
</aside>
```

So, if you have no interactive content, use `<a>`; otherwise, use JavaScript. That's my take, anyway.

Additionally, I'd also assert that, because `<a>` has text-level semantics, anything that isn't text-like should be made clickable with JavaScript instead of `<a>`. That said, plenty of folks write e.g. `<a href="..."><img ...></a>`, and images surely aren't text-like. So it's a murky topic at best.

Comment: In the example above H1 and P tags are block level and the anchor wraps around those. I also through anchors were inline elements and shouldn't wrap block level elements.

Comment: I thought the same thing, but reading the W3 document that I linked, I learned that `<a>` is now considered "transparent", meaning it takes on the content model of its parent element. Essentially, you can put anything inside an `<a>` as long as that stuff would be valid on its own without the `<a>`.